# What is the mathematical name of the 3D structure created by a spinning top?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am performing a mathematical exploration into the mathematics of ballet. I began by examining the fouetté turns and I thought that the shape/structure created when the ballet turns would be a helix. However, my further research led me to the following video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5VgOdgptRg

Using this I began looking at the ballerina as a spinning top while she performs the fouetté turn. I would like to graph this 3D shape ,created by the ballerina when she turns, on a graphing software such as Autograph. However, I am unable to figure out the equation of a spinning top or how to graph it. Is there a specific mathematical name or equation for the shape of a spinning top? How can it be graphed?

Comment: Are you talking a spinning top like in *Inception*?

Comment: What do yo mean by shape? Every point of a spinning top follows a circular trajectory (at most an epicycle), at least when the rotation is stable. In the case of the ballerina are you interested in graphing the trajectory of her up foot?

Comment: So by shape, I'm looking to graph a shape similar to 

https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/169/490307758/stock-vector-spinning-top-toy-490307758.jpg  

This is assuming a stable axis of rotation. For instance, if the dancer in the following picture is rotated about a stable axis (namely the leg on the ground) what structure would be described by the other bent leg which is rotating? 

http://pad1.whstatic.com/images/thumb/f/f9/Do-Ballet-Fouette-Turns-Step-2.jpg/aid2053216-728px-Do-Ballet-Fouette-Turns-Step-2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is best explained by the following link: http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2012/02/motion-of-a-spinning-top/. Also the following link would help: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/explore/michaelspages/Spin.htm.